# Auto create pandas column based on a define number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how can I define a function to dynamically create a pandas data frame and the number of columns based on a user input number?

For example:
no_levels = 3

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
def create(cols):
    col=['Level'+str(x) for x in range(1,cols+1)]
    return pd.DataFrame(columns=col)


create(4)
```

**OR**

as @anky suggested:

```
def create(cols):
    return pd.DataFrame(columns=range(1,cols+1)).add_prefix("Level")

create(4)
```

Output:

```
Level1  Level2  Level3  Level4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({})
no_lvl=int(input("number of levels"))
for lvl in range(no_lvl):
    df["level_"+str(lvl+1)]=None
```